# With NGXS, what is the recommended way of calling the backend before calling the local state

Tags: angular, ngxs

I'm starting a new angular app and doing the setup for the team.
One thing I'm wondering: where do you put the logic to access the backend?

In my (first) case, about the accounts/auth, I need to store, username/email/accessToken, and typically every time a token is received, I want to start a timer to refresh the access token before it expires.

After some research, I see that some people recommend having the API call in the action handler in my State. But honestly, it feels a bit like mixing different responsibility, and since this will be for quite a big application, I'm a bit concerned that we end up with a state class that will be huge. Also in this case, when I receive my token, I need to have a timer to refresh it. I was more seing NGXS as a library to apply mutation on my state and propagate changes, not something should be responsible of having such logic(I'm maybe wrong?)

So, is there a recommended way of doing this with NGXS? Should we call a service that does the API call and then dispatch an action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the NGXS with Facade design pattern is helpful in this case, which can:

> - Improve the readability and usability of a software library by masking
>   interaction with more complex components behind a single (and often
>   simplified) API;
> - Provide a context-specific interface to more generic
>   functionality (complete with context-specific input validation);
> - Serve
>   as a launching point for a broader refactor of monolithic or
>   tightly-coupled systems in favor of more loosely-coupled code.

You can read more about NGXS Facade here:

https://medium.com/ngxs/ngxs-facade-3aa90c41497b

Comment: That's a really nice approach.  One thing I'm not sure: I've a lot of selectors currently(by example for the UI state). On your link, it only selects the whole state. How would you have those selector with the facade? And what if for one case(like an interceptor) you need a snapshot of a property of the state and not an observable?

Comment: Regarding the first question, you can use any selector within `@Select()` decorator or `this.store.select()` function, not only the whole state one. Regarding the second question, I think you can create a function to return the snapshot value that you need such as `getToken() {this.store.selectSnapshot(tokenSelector)}`, which is better, or you can simply expose a new `selectSnapshot` function from the facade service which wraps the store one, then use it where ever you need.

Comment: Okay I see, I was hopping there was another Selector, like @SelectSnapshot, but anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks! Actually there are a @SelectSnapshot decorator but it’s available through ngxs-lab, and not merged yet with the ngxs core. Check it here: https://github.com/ngxs-labs/select-snapshot